# Why we need JBoss Tools in JEE development?

Tags: jboss-tools

I am JEE developer, well and in some projects always when I setup and work with JBoss Tools in Eclipse I always experience pain.

Can somebody tell me a reason why we need JBoss Tools? (I mean reason beyond what Red Hat advertise)

Comment: Alexander, nobody forces you to use it. However, it helps lots of devs to simplify much of their daily routine. If you have any particular remarks, you can report it in the JBoss Tools jira: https://issues.jboss.org/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=3410

Comment: I found very strange that nobody bothered to answer my question, well  i can only think about openShift support, which JBoss Tools proivides.